# (Ionic 3) Background mode plugin stops background playback of media on iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an application for iOS and Android using **Ionic 3** (3.9.2) and Cordova, on Windows 10.

The application uses the [Background Mode Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) to send the application to the background with the back-button press on Android.

However, it seems that this plugin is causing unusual behaviour on iPhone devices (tested on iOS 12 and 14). **If there is audio playing in the background (say, music from Spotify), and I open (start-up) my app, the music (and any other media) stops.**

This issue **does not present itself when running the app on the iPhone simulator** (from XCODE).
Removing the plugin also stops the problem on iOS, but the functionality is important to the app.
**The problem is exclusive to iOS devices.**

I have also tried using the [App Minimize Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-minimize/) but it **did not work** correctly on my app, but that is another story.

The same can be said for the [Allow Audio Plugin](https://github.com/davidfig/cordova-allow-background-audio).

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.